# How many different combinations for a combination lock if...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

If:

- The lock has 3 selection of numbers each ranging from 1 to 39.
- No number can be used twice in a row but the same number may occur
  both first and third.

For example, 20 13 20 would be acceptable but 20 20 13 would not.

How many different combinations are possible?

I was thinking of 39^3 - 39, but that only takes out the non adjacent repetitions.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: There are $39$ choices for the first number. For every such choice, there are $38$ choices for the second number. For every such $\dots$.

Comment: Yes I get that but I can't figure out how to find the value without the adjacent repetitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

39 choices for the first number, then the second must be different so there are 38 choices for that, then the third can't be the same as the second, but can be the same as the first so there are 38 choices for the third number.

Comment: Thanks for that but since this is a combination lock and that order matters, would we have to multiply (39*38*38) by 2?

Comment: this includes all possible orderings.  Try it out for yourself with the same instructions but lock selection has only #1-3 as a choice.   You will get 3*2*2 possibilities.  Try writing down each possibility to verify.